# putting quotation marks in `alias` is `CSH`

Tags: linux, alias, csh

I want to have an alias that will execute the fallowing command:

```
zgrep 'failed at' $PWD/RESULTS/log_dir/* | cut -d"'" -f2,4 | tr "'" "\t"
```

I've tried different ways to put it to an alias but none of them seem to work.
for example, some of my tries:

```
alias get_failed "zgrep 'failed at' $PWD/RESULTS/log_dir/* | cut \"\'\" -f2,4 | tr \"\'\" \"\\t\""
alias get_failed "zgrep 'failed at' $PWD/RESULTS/log_dir/* | cut \"\'\" -f2,4 | tr \"\'\" \"\\t\"
```

and others, how can I make my alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by a csh feature: you can't escape " if you already are in a "-quoted string (it's the same for '). This is still the default due to compatibility issues. You could either use a saner shell or use the `backslash_quote` configuration:

```
set backslash_quote
alias get_failed "zgrep 'failed at' $PWD/RESULTS/log_dir/* | cut -d\"'\" -f 2,4 | tr \"'\" \"\\t\""
```

Also, note that your call to cut removes any single quote (') so your tr call won't do much. (Edited my answer a few times to make sure it fits exactly to your original command.)

Comment: are you sure about `backslash_quote`? That sounds like a `tcsh` extension. Good luck to all.

Comment: Yeah, I found it in the man of `csh`. `tcsh` is just an enhanced `csh`, so they kept `backslash_quote`. And I did test the command I gave (just replaced zgrep by echo).

Comment: @Cygal, I works, how can I put it in `.aliases` file, so that I'll have that alias every time I open a new shell?

Comment: What is .aliases? You need to put `set backslash_quote` in your `~/.cshrc` before any mention to aliases or this `.alias` file. `~/.chsrc` is read by every shell on startup.